# How to wrap two different protocols into one api?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am working with two different protocols that are wrapped into one class which the system calls. The wrapper calls the appropriate protocol based on the provided protocol type. **Protocol A and B have about 90% common functions but there are several important functions that are exclusive to each protocol.** Currently I am handling the protocol-specific functions by them public and using friend classes.

This seems to do the trick but I feel like there must be a way to handle these types of issues in a better way. I am self-taught so I lack knowledge in these areas. What are design patterns to handle these types of issues?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an abstract class (i.e. at least one virtual function = 0), implement the common functions in this class.
2. Inherit this class for protocol A, and B and implement the differing functions.
3. (optional) make a factory class, which returns a unique_ptr for protocol A or protocol B, depending on the enum you give it.

Comment: Note that an abstract class should almost always have a virtual destructor.

Comment: @jxh yeah, I started writing an example implementation with virtual destructor = 0, but for some reason it refused writing it as code, so I gave up...

Comment: You are not allowed to create a pure virtual destructor.

Comment: @jxh if you still provide an implementation for the pure virtual destructor it is allowed, and it forces the inheriting classes to implement it.

Comment: The point of the virtual destructor is so that the destructor of the derived class gets called if delete is called on a pointer to the abstract class. It does not force the derived class to implement a destructor, it is just to make sure it gets called (even if the derived class only has a default destructor, it will get called if the abstract class has a virtual destructor).